# is ggplot confused? It exchanges the color labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend, density-plot

I'm drawing density plot with ggplot, but in the output it inverts the name of the colors!

This is my script:

```
ggplot(dataset) + 
  geom_density( aes( x = `Real Wage 1`, fill = "red"), alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_density( aes( x = `Real Wage 2`, fill = "blue"), alpha = 0.5)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image: Histograms]

Why is this happening? Am I setting something wrong?

Comment: You must give grouping column name from your dataset in the fill= option. For example fill = group. The group column in your dataset

Comment: If you put `colour = "red"` inside the `aes()` function, you map it to a scale. If you use it outside the `aes()` function, you use it directly without going through a scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by teunbrand, `ggplot` works by either grouping or individual colouring.

Anything included in `aes` will be treated as if referring to a column or variable. If you specify a string in `aes` this'll be interpreted as a variable of length 1. To obtain the behaviour you're seeking specify `fill` outside the `aes` parameter

```
ggplot(dataset) + 
  geom_density( aes( x = `Real Wage 1`), fill = "red", alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_density( aes( x = `Real Wage 2`), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5)+
  theme_classic()
```

A more thoughrough (and beginner friendly guide) to ggplot colouring is available at [stdha](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-density-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization). Give it a read, it is quite good for beginners and short.

Comment: Edited link to the one specifically working with density plots.